# Unable to get total to decrease

Tags: java, if-statement

I'm currently working on this pretty challenging program that I'm having a hard time understanding. I've gotten pretty far with it but I'm having trouble getting the amount of candy to decrease after each loop. How would I get each pot of candy to decrease along with the total amount? Thank you for your help!

```
import java.util.Random;

public class TreatHouse {  
   int candyPot1; // # of candy in pot 1
   int candyPot2; // # of candy in pot 2
   int currentPot; // 1 or 2
   int candyPot;
   int totalCandy;
   int currentTreaters;
   int treatsPerTreater;

   public TreatHouse(int candyPot, int totalCandy) {
      // ints variable currentPot by parameter candyPot, prints message
      if(candyPot !=1 && candyPot !=2) {
         //candyPot = 1;
         currentPot = 1;
         System.out.println("Invalid input, we will use candy pot 1 first.");               
   }

      //ensures total # of candy is more than zero   
      if(totalCandy <= 0){
         this.totalCandy = 0;
         System.out.println("We can't give out candy if we don't have any. "
                                 +"\nI think we have some from last year. Yep, we have 100 pieces " 
                                    +"\nof candy to give out.");
       }else
         this.totalCandy = totalCandy;

      // splits the candy between the pots                              
      this.totalCandy = this.totalCandy + 100;                              
      candyPot1 =  this.totalCandy/2;
      candyPot2 =  this.totalCandy - candyPot1;
   }

      public int getCandyCount() {
         return candyPot1 + candyPot2; 
      }

      public void passOutCandy() {
        /*if there are enough treats per treater for the given amount per treater, 
            pass out candy from the current pot 

            else display a messagethat the treaters have been tricked (No candy!)
                  but don't change the current pot*/

         if(currentPot == 1) {
             if (treatsPerTreater*currentTreaters <= candyPot1) {
                  candyPot1 = candyPot1 - (treatsPerTreater*currentTreaters);
             } else  {  
                  System.out.println("Sorry you've been tricked! No treats for you..."); 
             }    
               currentPot = 2;          
         }
         else if (currentPot == 2){
             if (treatsPerTreater*currentTreaters <= candyPot2) {
                  candyPot2 = candyPot2 - (treatsPerTreater*currentTreaters);
             }   
            else{
                  System.out.println("Sorry you've been tricked! No treats for you..."); 
              }   
                  currentPot = 1;       
         }
      }

      // Sets the # of trick or treaters
      public void knockKnock() {
         Random gen = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
            this.currentTreaters = gen.nextInt(13)+1; // 1 to 13 treaters
      }   

      // Displays how much candy in each pot, total candy left
      public void getCandyStatus() {
         System.out.println("We have " +this.candyPot1+ " pieces of candy left in pot 1 and " +
                  this.candyPot2 + " pieces of candy left in pot 2.");
         System.out.println("There's a total of " + (this.totalCandy) + " pieces of candy in the two pots.");                       
      }             

      //returns the pot number for which candy was last given
      public int getLastPot() {   
         return candyPot;
      }

      public void setTreatsPerTreater(int treatsPerTreater) {
         treatsPerTreater = currentTreaters*2;
      }
 }
```

Here's the driver program:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

   public class Halloween {
      public static void main (String[] args) {

      Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

      System.out.println("Which candy should we give out first? Candy from pot 1 or pot 2?");
      int candyPot = scan.nextInt();

      System.out.println("How much candy did we buy?");
      int totalCandy = scan.nextInt();

      TreatHouse ourHouse = new TreatHouse(candyPot, totalCandy);

      while(ourHouse.getCandyCount()>0) {
         ourHouse.getCandyStatus(); 

         System.out.println("How much candy per treater should we give out?");
         int treatsPerTreater = scan.nextInt();
         ourHouse.setTreatsPerTreater(treatsPerTreater);

         System.out.println("Knock, knock..." + "Trick or treat!!");
         ourHouse.knockKnock();
         ourHouse.passOutCandy();

         }

      System.out.println("Time to turn off the lights and go to bed!"); 
      System.out.println("The last candy came from pot number " +ourHouse.getLastPot());
      System.out.println("Happy Halloween!");
      scan.close();

   }
}
```

Comment: What is the total? answer : the sum of the parts. How do you do a sum? answer : with the + operator. When do you want to udpate your total? answer : that's up to you, but probably after one of the parts changed

Comment: Really, the more I read your post the less I understand your problem. You've got a getCandyCount() function that gets the total. You say you want the total to decrease, but you already decrement the currentPot in the passOutCandy() function, which leads to the total of candies decreasing.

Answer (score 0):

Hint - get rid of `this.totalCandy` - you don't need it after the constructor is finished, all candy has been divided into the pots.

Keeping the total in a separate variable is needless since you can compute it from candy amount in each pot - in fact having the same number (total candy) represented in two ways (as `totalCandy` and as a sum of candy in all pots) makes the program harder to write correctly and harder to maintain; and in your case it is indeed the cause of the problem. This advice is also known as [Don't Repeat Yourself principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the problem is here

```
public void setTreatsPerTreater(int treatsPerTreater) {
     treatsPerTreater = currentTreaters*2;
}
```

Here you are not using the param passed. `currentTreaters` is 0, which will lead to `treatsPerTreater` being 0 as well. So when you call `ourHouse.passOutCandy();`, `values of pot 1 and 2 dont change.

Answer (score 0):

The only place where you might be going wrong(as far as I can tell) is here,

```
  public void setTreatsPerTreater(int treatsPerTreater) {
     treatsPerTreater = currentTreaters*2;
  }
```

Here, when you modify `treatsPerTreater` you are changing the local variable `treatsPerTreater` and not the class variable.

Maybe you meant to say,

```
  public void setTreatsPerTreater(int treatsPerTreater) {
     this.treatsPerTreater = treatsPerTreater;
  }
```

This is called `shadowing`.

> Some declarations may be shadowed in part of their scope by another declaration of the same name, in which case a simple name cannot be used to refer to the declared entity.

Please read [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.4.1) for more details.
Also have a look at [Jiri Tousek's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33550513/4042839)